# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of undefined jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am trying to get the name of the div block when I click it. But I see an error in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of undefined.

The code is:

```js
    $(window).click(function(element) {
       alert(element.srcElement.className);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="root">
            <div class="wrap_question_container">
                <fieldset class="new_question"><legend>Question</legend>
                    <p>
                        <label for="question_title">Title: </label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Question Title" name="question_title" required><br>
                    </p>
                    <div class="choice_add"></div>
                </fieldset>
            </div><br>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit_val">
```

how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/srcElement)

> `Event.srcElement` is a proprietary alias for the standard `Event.target` property. It is specific to old versions of Microsoft Internet Explorer.

So change `element.srcElement.className` to `element.target.className`. You can also use `this.className`, since jQuery sets `this` to the event target.

```js
$(window).click(function(element) {
  alert(element.target.className);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="root">
  <div class="wrap_question_container">
    <fieldset class="new_question">
      <legend>Question</legend>
      <p>
        <label for="question_title">Title:</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Question Title" name="question_title" required>
        <br>
      </p>
      <div class="choice_add"></div>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
  <br>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit_val">
```

BTW, using a variable named `element` to hold the `Event` argument is very confusing. It's common to name it either `event` or `e`.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to use classes and get the class on the click - use HTML5's data attributes and on clicking the div - get the name from the data attribute. Of course if you are styling the divs based on the class - you will need to leave that in as well as adding the data attribute, but this is a nice way of getting information about the clicked div.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.root div').click(function(){
    var name = $(this).attr('data-name');
    console.log(name);
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="root">
            <div data-name="wrap_question_container">
                <fieldset class="new_question"><legend>Question</legend>
                    <p>
                        <label for="question_title">Title: </label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Question Title" name="question_title" required><br>
                    </p>
                    <div data-name="choice_add"></div>
                </fieldset>
            </div><br>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit_val">
```

Comment: While this is great advice, it doesn't really answer the question. You completely side-stepped the question about `element.srcElement`.

Comment: @Barmar - sidestepped because your answer covered that issue. I was simply trying to provide an alternative to the existing method that uses a better methodology. Sometimes the best answer is to stop using one approach and switch to a different one that the OP may not know about. Thereby rendering the original question redundant. In this case - I would far rather get the data-name than trying to get the class name.What happens when another class is added to the div? A better approach does not need to reference the poorer approach. In my opinion. But your answer was very good.

Comment: If you want to suggest alternate methods, do it in a comment. You won't be able to post full code, but that's OK. Answers are supposed to answer the question. No one looking for alternatives to using the class is going to find your answer, because the question title doesn't suggest it.